# Hibernate связь @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Имеются таблицы: `profession`, `subject`. Таблицы связаны отношением многие-ко-многим (таблица `subject_has_profession`).

Для таблиц `profession`, `subject` были созданы domain,repository,service,Impliment

Нужно ли создавать отдельно таблицу `subject_has_profession`?
и для нее (domain,repository,service,Impliment).

**Subject**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="subject")
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "SubjectName")
    private String subjectName;

    public Subject(String subjectName)
    {
        this.subjectName=subjectName;
    }

    public Subject( ){}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    /* Много(Subject)- ко Многим(Subjects) ???*/
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "subject_has_subject",
            joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "Subject_id",referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Subject_id1",referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Subject1> subjects1;

    public Set<Subject1> getSubjects(){
        return subjects1;
    }

    public void setSubjects(Set<Subject1> subjects1){
        this.subjects1=subjects1;
    }

    /*Много(Subject)- ко Многим(Profession) */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "subject_has_profession",
            joinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name = "Subject_id",referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Profession_id",referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Profession> professions;

    public Set<Profession> getProfessions() {
        return professions;
    }

    public void setProfessions(Set<Profession> professions) {
        this.professions = professions;
    }
}
```

**Profession**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="profession")
public class Profession {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Profession_Name")
    private String professionName;

    public Profession(){}

    public Profession(String professionName){
        this.professionName =professionName;
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProfessionName() {
        return professionName;
    }

    public void setProfessionName(String professionName) {
        this.professionName = professionName;
    }

     /*Много(Subject)- ко Многим(Profession) */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST},mappedBy = "professions")
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(Set<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}
```

Делала по этому примеру
http://devcolibri.com/2046

Comment: В `JPA` таблицы связей нигде, кроме объявления всяких `Many`, не используются. Нет ни запросов к ним, ни какой-либо возможности изменять стандартным образом. Ничего с ними боле делать не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Subject` и `Profession` - это сущности. `subject_has_profession` - это таблица связи и существует она только в БД. Напрямую с ней работает только Hibernate, делая выборку или изменяя несколько таблиц, если это необходимо.

Пока в ней только два поля - два внешних ключа, - как сущности ее нет, она не сущность, она связь. Вот если в ней появятся дополнительные поля - тогда да, она превращается в сущность, `ManyToMany` преобразуется в две пары `@OneToMany` и `@ManyToOne` и так далее.